# How To Pass A Number From VueJS Input Component?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I have an Element UI input in a VueJS component.

Currently, no matter what I've tried, it's returning a string.  I need a Decimal.  How's this done in VueJS?

Here's the input:

```
    <el-input id="initial-percent-input" type="number" min="0" max=100 :value="initialPercentState" 
      v-model.number="initialPercentState"
      @keyup.native="turnOffColumnPercent"  @click.native="turnOffColumnPercent"
      @change="changeInitialPercent"
    >
      <template slot="append">%</template>
    </el-input>
```

I've tried binding as explained here:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Literal-vs-Dynamic

I've tried v-model.number

I'm still returning a string??

Comment: Your example works: https://jsfiddle.net/zzqsqzsn/1/. What do you mean when you say "returning a string"? Where are you seeing the string value?

Comment: I see you used v-model.number.  Can you see any reason why my code above isn't working?  What am I doing differently?

Comment: Nothing else in your example would be directly affecting the string type. The only other thing I could think of is that somewhere else in your component, `this.initialPercentState` is being affected in a way that changes its value to a string